# Pandas dataframe.loc method too slow

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with +100K rows like this:

```
   user  document
0  john      book
1  jane   article
2  jane      book
3  jane      book
4   jim   article
5  john      book
6   jim  blogpost
7  jane  blogpost
8  jane  blogpost
9  jane  blogpost
```

I need the dataframe like this:

```
      blogpost  article  book
john         1        3     0
jane         0        0     1
jim          4        0     2
```

That is, I need numbers of downloads for every `user, document` combination.

I'm doing `.groupby(['user', 'document'])` and then use `df.loc` to set download number:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=users, columns=documents)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

grouped = records.groupby(['user', 'document'])
for elem in grouped:
    user, document = elem[0]
    downloads = len(elem[1])
    df.loc[user, document] = downloads
```

However, `df.loc` is very slow when used this way... I've commented out `df.loc..` line and found that the loop completes fast, so almost certainly it's `df.loc` access that is slow.

How can I get this result faster?

Minimum working example:

```
records = pd.DataFrame([
    ('john', 'book'), 
    ('jane', 'article'),
    ('jane','book'),
    ('jane','book'),
    ('jim', 'article'), 
    ('john', 'book'),
    ('jim', 'blogpost'), 
    ('jane', 'blogpost'),
    ('jane', 'blogpost'),
    ('jane', 'blogpost')
    ], columns=['user', 'document'])
print(records)

users = list(set(records['user']))
users.sort()
documents = list(set(records['document']))
documents.sort()

print(users)
print(documents)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=users, columns=documents)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)

grouped = records.groupby(['user', 'document'])
for elem in grouped:
    user, document = elem[0]
    downloads = len(elem[1])
    df.loc[user, document] = downloads
```

Comment: I experienced the same thing. it is indeed very slow. instead i define empy lists out side the loop and append the data to the lists and equal specific column of df to the these lists. it is way faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of ways achieves this without loop, `pivot` , `pivot_table`, `crosstab`, `groupby count`

```
pd.crosstab(df.user,df.document)
Out[1283]: 
document  article  blogpost  book
user                             
jane            1         3     2
jim             1         1     0
john            0         0     2
```

Comment: oooooo. Never knew about `crosstab`. Very handy.

Comment: @Wen Great tip. Thanks!

Comment: @Nivi Yw~ :-)  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can access cell values with numpy by converting your dataframe
to a numpy array. This method is faster than the .loc method.
However you do need to know the positioning of your columns. In the below
example I want the value in the B column that corresponds with 2 in the A
column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]} )

# Make sure our A and B are where we think they are (optional)
A = df.columns.get_loc('A')
B = df.columns.get_loc('B')

# Convert to numpy array
df = df.values

# Get the value
B_val = df[:,B][ df[:,A] == 2 ][0]  

# Convert back to dataframe (optional)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['A','B','C'])

#B_val = 5
```

You can also convert the dataframe to a dictionary and access values that way. This is slightly faster than the .at[] method and much faster than the .loc[] method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]} )

# Convert to dictionary
df = df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')
num = 2
B_val = df[num][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
df.set_index('user')['document'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
      article  blogpost  book
user                         
john        0         0     2
jane        1         3     2
jim         1         1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
records.groupby(['user','document']).size().unstack('document').fillna(0)
```